# The difference between do_action() and add_action() in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

After reading multiple online posts about do_action()/add_action(), I would like to brief my understanding about them.

Here I would only talk about action hooks, not about the filters.

```
do_action() : Registers an action hook
add_action() : adds a callback function to the registered hook.
```

Now the questions are :

1> **About add_action()/do_action() for existing hook :**

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_func');
```

In the above example the callback function my_func() is registered with the hook '**admin_enqueue_scripts**'. Now whenever **do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts')** is called somewhere inside the code in future, the callback function my_func() would be executed. So in brief, the callback function won't be executed unless **do_action()** is called. **Is my understanding correct ?**

2> **About add_action()/do_action() for custom hook:**

Now consider a situation I am writing a new plugin and I want to provide an action hook inside it. In this case how these two functions would be used ?

```
// inside my plugin code
do_action('my_custom_hook');

// inside the user code who wants to use this hook
function  user_func()
{
  // code ...
}
add_action('my_custom_hook', 'user_func');
```

**Is my understanding correct ?**

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct for both…